# How to filter XML data with the array values in query

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, xml

My question is how to filter the set of xml data with the an array of values. Here the below jquery code and xml data. kind help to solve the issue. I had used the filter function though its not working

JS - Code

```
    var data = response.results[1][0].Variant;
    var arrdata = data.split(';');
    arrdata.shift(); // *result : ["1", "2", "3"]*
    function loadfail(){
        alert("Error: Failed to Load Menu Data : XML");
        }
        $.ajax({
        url: '/Prueba/FCD/menudata/menu.xml',  
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: menu,
        error: loadfail
        });
function menu(document){
                $(document).find("variant")
                .filter(function () {
                    return $(this).find('value').text()==arrdata
                })
                .each(function () {
                    var variant_Label = $(this).find('text').text();
                    var variant_Value = $(this).find('value').text();
                    $('#variant_model').append(
                   '<option value="'+ variant_Value + '">' + variant_Label + '</option>'
                    );
                })
            }
```

XML - Data

```
<menu>
<variant>
    <value>1</value>
    <text>12 pa</text>
</variant>
<variant>
    <value>2</value>
    <text>30 pa</text>
</variant>
<variant>
    <value>3</value>
    <text>40 pa</text>
</variant>
<variant>
    <value>4</value>
    <text>50 pa</text>
</variant>
</menu>
```

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"? Saying this alone is not helpful. What is your current code actually doing? What is the expected output or behaviour? In which way is it not working as you expect it to? Also, what have you tried to debug so far?

Comment: current code is displaying no options in the dropdown. the drop down should get filter with the value 1 , 2 ,3 (12 pa, 30 pa, 40 pa).

Comment: Have you `console.log()` things? Like `$(this).find('value')`? To see if it's correct?

Comment: no result is getting output. some mistake in filter() function if that function alone remove all xml data is listing. but i need to filter data and list

Comment: so what's the output of `console.log( $(this).find('value') )` in the filter?

Comment: Also, try `.filter(function (variant) { console.log(variant)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML data is loaded and filtering the dynamic value and attributing it.

```
$("#variant_model").empty()

                    var data = response1.results[1][0].Variant;
                    var arrdata = data.split(';');
                    arrdata.shift();
                    function loadfail() {
                        alert("Error: Failed to Load Menu Data : XML");
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Prueba/FCD/menudata/menu.xml',
                        success: menu,
                        error: loadfail
                    });
                    console.log(arrdata);

                    function menu(document) {
                        var array2 = arrdata;
                        var array1 = []
                        $(document).find("variant").each(function () {
                            var text = $(this).find('text').text();
                            var value = $(this).find('value').text();
                            var combo = { text, value }
                            array1.push(combo)
                        })
                        array1 = array1.filter(function (item) {
                            return array2.includes(item.value);
                        })

                        array1.forEach(function (item) {
                            $("#variant_model").append($("<option></option>").val(item.value).html(item.text));
                        })
                        $('#variant_model option[value="' + response.item[0][0].Variant + '"]').attr('selected', true);

                    }
```